# more efficient string concatenation in grails

Tags: grails

I've got a tag I use to build up a string of personal attributes - height, hair color, eye color, and blood type.  All of these fields are optional to the user.  The final output string will look like:

brown hair, green eyes, 5'5", A+ blood type

But because the fields are optional the output could be:

green eyes

or

brown hair, 5'5"

Another wrench is if a person is bald, they don't have hair so the output is:

bald, blue eyes

My current tag looks like this:

```
def bodyStats = { attrs, body ->
    def applicant = attrs.applicant
    String stats = ''

    if (applicant.hairColor) {
        //if the applicant has hair, the output is <color> hair
        if (!HairColor.BALD.equals(applicant.hairColor)) {
            stats += g.message(code:'profile.hairColor', args:[applicant.hairColor])
        }
        //else it's just bald
        else {
            stats += applicant.hairColor
        }
    }
    if (applicant.eyeColor) {
        stats = stats ? (stats + ', ') : stats
        stats += g.message(code:'profile.eyeColor', args:[applicant.hairColor])
    }
    if (applicant.heightFeet) {
        stats = stats ? (stats + ', ') : stats
        stats += g.message(code:'profile.height', args:[applicant.heightFeet, applicant.heightInches])
    }
    if (applicant.bloodType) {
        stats = stats ? (stats + ', ') : stats
        stats += g.message(code:'profile.bloodType', args:[applicant.heightFeet, applicant.heightInches])
    }
    out << stats
}
```

For internationalization I'm pulling in things like 'hair' and 'eyes' from the messages.properties file.

Is this the best I can do?  I also have to account for commas between each attribute if there is a preceding attribute.

Another question is does this belong in a tag, or should building up this 'attributes' string belong in the domain object itself.

Comment: I think that this kind of question depends on the personal opinion, so it suits better in the user mail list. From faq: "Not all questions work well in our format. Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion rather than answers."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use "out" directly. It has a performance optimized buffer.